# Docker compose 'depends_on' referencing an undeclared service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker-compose and is running a poc to setup a tool named Datahub with it.
One thing confuses me is in docker-compose.yml, there is one line mentions **mysql-setup**, but I have absolutely no clue how does mysql service get provisioned (no specifications on required container image...), thanks a million for any inputs!!
https://github.com/datahub-project/datahub/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.yml#L69

```
  datahub-upgrade:
    container_name: datahub-upgrade
    hostname: datahub-upgrade
    image: ${DATAHUB_UPGRADE_IMAGE:-acryldata/datahub-upgrade}:${DATAHUB_VERSION:-head}
    command:
    - -u
    - SystemUpdate
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/datahub-upgrade/Dockerfile
    env_file: datahub-upgrade/env/docker-without-neo4j.env
    labels:
      datahub_setup_job: true
    depends_on:
      mysql-setup:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
      elasticsearch-setup:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Compose with [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/).  In particular, Compose will automatically look for a `docker-compose.override.yml` file, and if it's present, use the contents from both files.  There is a [`docker-compose.override.yml`](https://github.com/datahub-project/datahub/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.override.yml) file checked into the repository you show, and that defines a [`mysql-setup`](https://github.com/datahub-project/datahub/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.override.yml#L12) service.

A typical use of this setup is to put the core service definitions in the main `docker-compose.yml` and then environment-specific settings and support services in an override file.  For a database you might use a database on dedicated hardware or a hosted service in production, but a local container in development.  The main Compose file should still be self-contained, and I'd argue you shouldn't refer to a service in the main file that is only defined in the override file.

The [merge rules](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/13-merge) are specified to concatenate lists and combine maps by merging values, so a better way to express this would be to put an additional `depends_on:` block in the override file.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  datahub-upgrade:
    image: ${DATAHUB_UPGRADE_IMAGE:-acryldata/datahub-upgrade}:${DATAHUB_VERSION:-head}
    ...
    depends_on: [elasticsearch-setup, et-cetera]
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.override.yml
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ... a full normal service definition ...
  mysql-setup:
    image: ${DATAHUB_MYSQL_SETUP_IMAGE:-acryldata/datahub-mysql-setup}:${DATAHUB_VERSION:-head}
    ...
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
  datahub-upgrade:
    # only this one setting here
    depends_on:
      mysql-setup:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
```

I'd also consider how much these files could be simplified.  You rarely need to manually specify `container_name:` or `hostname:`, and I almost never see `labels:` used in a plain-Docker context.  If your Compose is new enough to support the "specification" file format (there is not a Compose file format 3.9 and the older version of Compose will reject these files) then you should also have access to [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) to selectively include services, which would simplify the various "just X" and "without Y" file variants in the repository.